# Nagios - Access Forbidden 403

Tags: nagios

I have seen a few question this regard, but unfortunately that does not solve my problem. Please let me know if you have been able to successfully run Nagios on OpenSuse on a virtual machine.

I have Open Suse installed in two different computers. one via VMware and one via VirtualBox and they run just fine for any other application. No problem on accessing network etc.

But after following the open Suse installation steps as mentioned at:
http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nagioscore/4/en/quickstart-opensuse.html

I find the "Access Forbidden! Error 403" messege when I start localhost/nagios (removed the http:// purposefully in the post) on firefox. The installation looks went through fine with no error. I am using OpenSuse 13.1 version, I tried with nagios version 4.0.6 and 4.0.7 along with plugins 2.0.2.

I made sure, apache(apache2), gcc, gcc++, kernel-source (as suggested in nagios forum by a user), php, apache2-mod_php5, make etc are all installed. apache2 service is running and was retasrted after  running:
make install-webconf

The username and password was rightly keyed in :).

Can you please guide me on what is going wrong on this.

Here is the apache2/error_log:

```
[Mon Jun 23 14:50:57.331306 2014] [autoindex:error] [pid 6138] [client 127.0.0.1:46061] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /srv/www/htdocs/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.html.var) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Jun 23 14:51:57.317399 2014] [autoindex:error] [pid 6139] [client 127.0.0.1:46066] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /srv/www/htdocs/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.html.var) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Jun 23 14:52:57.299316 2014] [autoindex:error] [pid 24637] [client 127.0.0.1:46068] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /srv/www/htdocs/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.html.var) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Jun 23 14:57:57.289446 2014] [autoindex:error] [pid 6137] [client 127.0.0.1:46077] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /srv/www/htdocs/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.html.var) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Jun 23 14:58:59.372027 2014] [autoindex:error] [pid 6136] [client ::1:59841] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /usr/local/nagios/share/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.html.var) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Jun 23 15:02:57.274830 2014] [autoindex:error] [pid 6139] [client 127.0.0.1:46119] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /srv/www/htdocs/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.html.var) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Jun 23 15:07:57.263871 2014] [autoindex:error] [pid 24637] [client 127.0.0.1:46143] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /srv/www/htdocs/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.html.var) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Jun 23 15:12:57.251875 2014] [autoindex:error] [pid 6137] [client 127.0.0.1:46147] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /srv/www/htdocs/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.html.var) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Jun 23 15:17:57.239626 2014] [autoindex:error] [pid 6135] [client 127.0.0.1:46152] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /srv/www/htdocs/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.html.var) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Jun 23 15:22:57.228968 2014] [autoindex:error] [pid 6136] [client 127.0.0.1:46155] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /srv/www/htdocs/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.html.var) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Jun 23 15:27:57.217628 2014] [autoindex:error] [pid 6138] [client 127.0.0.1:46158] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /srv/www/htdocs/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.html.var) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Jun 23 15:32:57.206081 2014] [autoindex:error] [pid 6139] [client 127.0.0.1:46161] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /srv/www/htdocs/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.html.var) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Jun 23 15:37:57.197239 2014] [autoindex:error] [pid 24637] [client 127.0.0.1:46165] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /srv/www/htdocs/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.html.var) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Jun 23 15:42:57.180851 2014] [autoindex:error] [pid 6137] [client 127.0.0.1:46168] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /srv/www/htdocs/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.html.var) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Jun 23 15:47:57.165708 2014] [autoindex:error] [pid 6135] [client 127.0.0.1:46172] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /srv/www/htdocs/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.html.var) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Jun 23 15:52:57.154070 2014] [autoindex:error] [pid 6136] [client 127.0.0.1:46174] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /srv/www/htdocs/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.html.var) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Jun 23 15:57:57.136265 2014] [autoindex:error] [pid 6138] [client 127.0.0.1:46182] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /srv/www/htdocs/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.html.var) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Jun 23 16:02:57.122498 2014] [autoindex:error] [pid 6139] [client 127.0.0.1:46186] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /srv/www/htdocs/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.html.var) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Jun 23 16:07:57.110446 2014] [autoindex:error] [pid 24637] [client 127.0.0.1:46191] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /srv/www/htdocs/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.html.var) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Jun 23 16:12:57.092886 2014] [autoindex:error] [pid 6137] [client 127.0.0.1:46197] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /srv/www/htdocs/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.html.var) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Jun 23 16:17:57.077070 2014] [autoindex:error] [pid 6135] [client 127.0.0.1:46204] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /srv/www/htdocs/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.html.var) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Jun 23 16:22:57.067403 2014] [autoindex:error] [pid 6136] [client 127.0.0.1:46206] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /srv/www/htdocs/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.html.var) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Jun 23 16:27:57.054625 2014] [autoindex:error] [pid 6138] [client 127.0.0.1:46209] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /srv/www/htdocs/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.html.var) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Jun 23 16:32:57.042447 2014] [autoindex:error] [pid 6139] [client 127.0.0.1:46213] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /srv/www/htdocs/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.html.var) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Jun 23 16:37:57.030372 2014] [autoindex:error] [pid 24637] [client 127.0.0.1:46219] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /srv/www/htdocs/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.html.var) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

Here is the apache2/acsess_log:

```
::1 - - [23/Jun/2014:14:58:59 -0700] "GET /nagios HTTP/1.1" 401 1233 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
::1 - nagiosadmin [23/Jun/2014:14:58:59 -0700] "GET /nagios HTTP/1.1" 301 310 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
::1 - - [23/Jun/2014:14:58:59 -0700] "GET /nagios/ HTTP/1.1" 403 1004 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
::1 - nagiosadmin [23/Jun/2014:15:01:43 -0700] "GET /nagios/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 1628 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jun/2014:15:02:57 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 403 1004 "-" "check_http/v2.0.2 (nagios-plugins 2.0.2)"
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jun/2014:15:07:57 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 403 1004 "-" "check_http/v2.0.2 (nagios-plugins 2.0.2)"
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jun/2014:15:12:57 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 403 1004 "-" "check_http/v2.0.2 (nagios-plugins 2.0.2)"
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jun/2014:15:17:57 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 403 1004 "-" "check_http/v2.0.2 (nagios-plugins 2.0.2)"
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jun/2014:15:22:57 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 403 1004 "-" "check_http/v2.0.2 (nagios-plugins 2.0.2)"
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jun/2014:15:27:57 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 403 1004 "-" "check_http/v2.0.2 (nagios-plugins 2.0.2)"
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jun/2014:15:32:57 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 403 1004 "-" "check_http/v2.0.2 (nagios-plugins 2.0.2)"
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jun/2014:15:37:57 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 403 1004 "-" "check_http/v2.0.2 (nagios-plugins 2.0.2)"
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jun/2014:15:42:57 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 403 1004 "-" "check_http/v2.0.2 (nagios-plugins 2.0.2)"
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jun/2014:15:47:57 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 403 1004 "-" "check_http/v2.0.2 (nagios-plugins 2.0.2)"
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jun/2014:15:52:57 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 403 1004 "-" "check_http/v2.0.2 (nagios-plugins 2.0.2)"
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jun/2014:15:57:57 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 403 1004 "-" "check_http/v2.0.2 (nagios-plugins 2.0.2)"
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jun/2014:16:02:57 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 403 1004 "-" "check_http/v2.0.2 (nagios-plugins 2.0.2)"
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jun/2014:16:07:57 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 403 1004 "-" "check_http/v2.0.2 (nagios-plugins 2.0.2)"
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jun/2014:16:12:57 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 403 1004 "-" "check_http/v2.0.2 (nagios-plugins 2.0.2)"
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jun/2014:16:17:57 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 403 1004 "-" "check_http/v2.0.2 (nagios-plugins 2.0.2)"
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jun/2014:16:22:57 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 403 1004 "-" "check_http/v2.0.2 (nagios-plugins 2.0.2)"
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jun/2014:16:27:57 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 403 1004 "-" "check_http/v2.0.2 (nagios-plugins 2.0.2)"
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jun/2014:16:32:57 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 403 1004 "-" "check_http/v2.0.2 (nagios-plugins 2.0.2)"
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jun/2014:16:37:57 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 403 1004 "-" "check_http/v2.0.2 (nagios-plugins 2.0.2)"
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jun/2014:16:42:57 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 403 1004 "-" "check_http/v2.0.2 (nagios-plugins 2.0.2)"
```

The conf file is:

```
ScriptAlias /nagios/cgi-bin "/usr/local/nagios/sbin"

<Directory "/usr/local/nagios/sbin">
#  SSLRequireSSL
   Options ExecCGI
   AllowOverride None
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
#  Order deny,allow
#  Deny from all
#  Allow from 127.0.0.1
   AuthName "Nagios Access"
   AuthType Basic
   AuthUserFile /usr/local/nagios/etc/htpasswd.users
   Require valid-user
</Directory>

Alias /nagios "/usr/local/nagios/share"

<Directory "/usr/local/nagios/share">
#  SSLRequireSSL
   Options None
   AllowOverride None
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
#  Order deny,allow
#  Deny from all
#  Allow from 127.0.0.1
   AuthName "Nagios Access"
   AuthType Basic
   AuthUserFile /usr/local/nagios/etc/htpasswd.users
   Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a really old thread,I face the similar issue today but in case of Centos7,The only thing I do to resolve this issue is adding index.php to DirectoryIndex parameter,not sure how much this is useful in case of OpenSuse

```
httpd.conf
```

Changed

```
 <IfModule dir_module>
  DirectoryIndex index.html
   </IfModule>
```

To

```
 <IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same problem (on a Raspberry Pi 3 w/ Raspian Jessie, using install instructions from http://www.howtovmlinux.com/articles/rasberry-pi/install-nagios-core-latest-version-4-x-x-on-raspberrypi-jessie.html) and I will shame-facedly admit that it was because I skipped a critical step in the installation: I neglected to do "make install"!

It seems unlikely that anyone else would make this same bonehead mistake, but in case they do, here's my solution: run "make install"! :-]

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue on CentOS 7 but I just installed the php package and it worked

```
yum install php-5.4
```